# How do I prove that a number $p>2$ is prime if and only if $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod {p}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> How do I prove that a number $p\geq2$ is prime if and only if $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod {p}$?

I really don't know where to start... Could someone help me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Proofs

Comment: Why do you exclude $p=2$?

Comment: Good question ;)

Comment: You can use Bézout's theorem from right to left !

Answer (score 4):

If $p$ is prime, then for any $x$ not divisible by $p$ there exists $y$ such that $xy\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ (this follows from the existence of $y$ and $z$ integers such that $xy + pz = 1$, as $x$ and $p$ are coprime. In particular, there exists such a number for each $n\in\{1,2,\dots, p-1\}$. This number is also unique modulo $p$, and the only case in which $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ is when $x\equiv 1$ or $x\equiv p-1$, as the residues modulo $p$ form a field and a polynomial of degree $n$ over a field can have at most $n$ solutions in the field. Thus, every $n\in\{2,\dots, p-2\}$ appears once in the factorial and will pair with its inverse to give $(p-1)!\equiv (p-1)\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot\dots\cdot 1\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

If $n$ is not prime, then there exists $r\mid n$ (say $rk = n$) such that $1 <r\leq n-1$ (hence $1 < k\leq n-1$), so that $(n-1)!k\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ But $k$ is both nonzero modulo $n$, so $(n-1)!$ could not have been $-1$ modulo $n$.